# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi menú desplegable se muestre sobre mi contenido HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que este menú hecho en HTML, CS y JS se muestre sobre el contenido de un .JS llamado "mapa.js". Soy apenas un estudiante y es mi primera vez programando con HTML, JS y CSS jeje

Aquí dejo el código del menú. El demás código del contenido que se muestre debajo del menú (el mapa) no lo creo conveniente, pero si es necesario, lo publico. Gracias!

[Captura 1](https://ibb.co/xGkJb7f)

[Captura 2](https://ibb.co/23QWVJ6)

[Captura 3](https://ibb.co/Zx6kdHs)

[Captura 4](https://ibb.co/MVQ6m08)

Comment: Es mejor si subes las imágenes directamente a este sitio.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Subir capturas de pantalla de código [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el articulo [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es con la superposición de elementos con css.
donde el elemento principal (el mapa en tj caso) debe tener posicion relativa y el elemento hijo ( el menu) se desplaza respecto a un eje z.
en código seria algo como:

```
.mapa{
  position:relative;
}
.menu{
  position:fixed,
  z-index:5
```

}

Puedes ir jugando con la la propiedad position de menu de fixed a absolute dependiendo de si quieres que sea en relación a una posición fija del elemento o de acuerdo con el elemento padre.
Recuerda que en el html debes colocarle el id="menu".